# QML import style file from subdirectory

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a problem with importing style files from a subdirectory.

This is the concerning section in my *.pro file:

```
QML_IMPORT_PATH = \
src/gui/qml/views/startview/ \
src/gui/qml/views/createlocalgameview/ \
src/gui/qml/views/ \
src/gui/qml/components/styles/ \
src/gui/qml/components/ \
src/gui/qml/js/
```

For example i have a file MyTextFieldStyle.qml placed in src/gui/qml/components/styles/:

```
TextFieldStyle {
    [...]
}
```

and i have a file TextArea.qml placed in src/gui/qml/components/:

```
Item {
    [...]
    TextField {
        id: textField
        style: MyTextFieldStyle {}
    }
    [...]
}
```

Now i get this error:

```
TextArea.qml: MyTextFieldStyle is not a type
```

If i put the MyTextFieldStyle.qml in the same directory like TextArea.qml (src/gui/qml/components/) it works fine. But i have many components and many styles and so i want to seperate them to have a better overview. Is there any way i can get this working?

Comment: It should be enough putting at the top of the file an `import` statement with relative paths. In your example, you can use `import './styles'`. Let me know if it works, I can create a response so that you may accept it for future searches.

Comment: Note: this QML_IMPORT_PATH *rap does not affect anything except may be Creator highlighting (surprize!) :0

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you very much. Please create an answer i can accept!

Comment: in order that your QML_IMPORT_PATH work you should create a qmldir file in the directory styles, in it you write  module Styles MyTextFieldStyle 1.0 MyTextFieldStyle.qml, and in your qml you do import Styles 1.0, I think it's better than importing the folder it self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough putting at the top of the file an `import` statement with relative paths.

In your example, you can use `import './styles'`.

As stated in the comments, `QML_IMPORT_PATH` is not meant to solve that problem.